# excel save as from multiple cells data -2 words on last cell

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

I have researched and come up with this code so far, but the last cell has the address formatted as: street address (# street name suffix) city, province. I need to exclude the city and province from the string to create the file name without creating a separate cell for the city and province (as the display in the printed document should be left justified and read ## street name city and province without any extra spaces). The info will change all the time so adjusting the cell width it not an option.

Does anyone know how to achieve this by modifying or enhancing the code below?

All help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
Sub SaveAsString()

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFolderPath As String

strFolderPath = "D:\Fire Alarm Services\"

    strPath = strFolderPath & _
    Range("K1").Value & " " & _
    Range("N10").Value & " " & _
    Range("H12").Value & " " & _
    Format(Range("H10").Value, "mmm dd yyyy") & ".xlsm"

fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(strPath _
, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

End Sub
```